# Como Inserir Mensagem do visual studio C# para a Queue no Azure?

Tags: microsoft-azure

Para inserir mensagem na queue eu executei esse código que parece estar correcto e no entanto, continua a não funcionar não sei porquê em que o erro que dá (na parte addmessage é 404 not found e pelo que vi na net as conexões parecem estar bem feitas.

O que está a verde foi outra tentativa de efetuar a mesma coisa de outra maneira.

O que poderá estar a originar este erro e como poderei dar fix nisto?

[image: codigo]

Comment: Ao invés de postar a imagem, poste o código porque facilita para quem for te ajudar. Use a opção `{}` para formatar o código. Faça um [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Para inserir uma mensagem em uma fila existente, primeiro crie uma nova CloudQueueMessage. Em seguida, chame o método AddMessage . Um CloudQueueMessage pode ser criado por meio de uma cadeia de caracteres (em formato UTF-8) ou de uma matriz de bytes. Este é o código que cria uma fila (se ela não existir) e insere a mensagem 'Hello, World':

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the queue client.
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a queue.
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("myqueue");

// Create the queue if it doesn't already exist.
queue.CreateIfNotExists();

// Create a message and add it to the queue.
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("Hello, World");
queue.AddMessage(message);
```

Fonte: [Introdução ao Azure Message Queue > Como inserir uma mensagem na fila](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#insert-a-message-into-a-queue)